# Can a function be differentiable everywhere on its domain, but not Lipschitz on its domain?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

If we suppose that a function is differentiable at every point on its domain (but place no more restrictions than that), does it follow that the function is Lipschitz on its domain? I think that it does not, and I suspect that it is because we do not require that the function is continuously differentiable. But I'm not sure how to prove my thought - specifically, I can't come up with a counterexample.

If I am right that it is not Lipschitz, can we say if it will be locally Lipschitz at every point?

Comment: $f(x)=\sqrt x$ on $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is the function defined by $f(x)=x^2$, then $f$ is differentiable and even a $C^\infty$ function, but it is not Lipschitz continuous.

On the other hand, if you define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)&\text{ if }x\ne0\\0&\text{ if }x=0,\end{cases}\end{array}$$then $f$ is not Lipschitz continuous on any neighborhood of $0$. This has to do with the fact that $f'$ is unbounded (which is stronger than being discontinuous).

Comment: So it is the boundedness of the function (or its derivative), at least in a neighbourhood, that allows us to conclude Lipschitz continuity?

Comment: Every continuous function is locally bounded. But if the derivative of a function is unbounded, then $f$ may not be locally Lipschitz continuous.